# html 5 range slider for touch devices? alternatives to jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, android, css

I'm looking for a slider that I can use on touch devices. Are there any alternatives to jquery mobile?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is always the alternative of creating your own slider ;)

Comment: are talking about an image slider or a ui range slider?

Comment: talking about a range slider. I did try to create my own using hot studio touch library. The problem was the animation was not smooth. I'm assuming it's an android thing. Here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/bullrout/rR77u/1/

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with a html5 range input?

```
<input id="some_id" type="range"/>
```

[Usage Example](http://jsfiddle.net/VtPsf/2/)

[Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.range.html)

Comment: I thought that there might have been a library I could leverage from. I'll give that one a try.